# Two dimensions geometry problem

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

Determine the vector equation and parametric equations of the line in $\Bbb R^2$ passing through $A=(1, 3)$ parallel to the line passing through $B=(-1, 4)$ and $C=(2, 1)$. Find out if the line intersects the coordinate planes. 
Find out when the line intersects the coordinate axes. When intersection, calculate it.

So (...)

**Vector Ecuation**

If the line passes through a point I must to use $tB+A$, but this line passes through two points, so $t(C-B) + A$

Then the vector equation is: $t(3, -5) + (1,3)$

**Parametric equations**

$x =(x_1, x_2)$

So (...)

$x_1 = 3t+1$

$x_2 = -5t+3$

**Coordinate planes**

In $\Bbb R^2$ the coordinate plane is $XY$
So, if the line intersects the XY coordinate plane, both components must be 0,
that is $3t+1 = 0$ and $-5t+3 = 0$.
But for the first component is 0, $t$ must be $-{1\over3}$ and for the second component, $t$ must be $3\over5$, then there's no value for $t$ that makes both components $0$.

**Coordinate axes**

There's twoo axes in $\Bbb R^2$, $X$ and $Y$.

The line intersecting the axis x: $t$ must be $-{1\over3}$ so the line is $(0,{{14}\over3})$

The line intersecting the axis Y: $t$ must be ${3\over5}$ so the line is $({{14}\over5},0)$

The question is, all these solutions are correct? 
In case that I'm wrong, could someone orient me to find the solutions?

Answer (score 0):

1. $C-B=(3,-3)$, else the *parametric* equation is correct.
2. For the *vector equation*, one uses the *normalvector* of the line, that is orthogonal to $C-B$, so it is $(3,3)$ for example, or any parallel to it, let's take $(1,1)$. Then the left hand side of the equation goes like $1\cdot x+1\cdot y$, and you have to write the number on the right hand side such that $A$ satisfies it: $$x+y=4\,.$$
3. The coordinate *planes*??? Is it serious? Well, yes, there is only one coordinate plane on the plane, and that's the plane itself, and the line is intersecting it in all of its points.
4. Recalculate with $(3,-3)$, or use the vector equation with $x=0$ and $y=0$, respectively.